# A few questions about Swan's theorem.

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles

I've been reading [Swan's paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1993627) on vector bundles over compact Hausdorff spaces and projective modules. Since this is my first time learning about the topic, I'd appreciate if anyone can explain to me a few details about his proof.  My questions are as follows

1. In page 265 he notes every section can be written as a combination of sections and scalars which depend on elements of the base space. $s(y)=\sum a_i(y) s_i(y)$. Can someone perhaps elaborate on his argument that a section is continuous if and only if each a_i is continuous?
2. The second question is how is $\Gamma$ an additive functor. I can't seem to find a proof of this nor be able to come up with one myself.
3. In corollary 5 in page 268. Why is it clear that $\xi ' \cong \xi$?
4. In Propositon 1 on page 265. Why is (3) equivalent to (4)?
5. In corollary 3 on page 267. I'm able to understand the function $s \mapsto s(x)$ is bijective but I can't catch as what structure they are isomorphic as.

Comment: 1. The non-trivial direction holds only if the $s_i$ are pointwise linearly independent (I assume they are, but can see only page 264). But in that case, it is clear, isn't it?